# TclError: unknown option "0.0": must be moveto or scroll

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

My program consists in mouse drawing: Simultaneous reproduction of the drawn curves are done on a toplevel window. My aim is to set the vertical and horizontal scroll bars to the toplevel window.

The drawing works as I expected except I am not seeing the scrollbars as well as I am getting this error (which does not stop the program, however):

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1489, in __call__
            return self.func(*args)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1523, in yview
             res = self.tk.call(self._w, 'yview', *args)
TclError: unknown option "0.0": must be moveto or scroll
```

The program consists of these lines:

```
from Tkinter import *
import numpy as np
import cv2
import Image, ImageTk

class Test:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.b1="up"
        self.xold=None
        self.yold=None
        self.liste=[]
        self.top = TopLevelWindow()
        self.s=400,400,3
        self.im=np.zeros(self.s,dtype=np.uint8)
        cv2.imshow("hello",self.im)
    def test(self):
        self.drawingArea=Canvas(self.parent,width=400,height=400)
        self.drawingArea.pack() 
        self.drawingArea.bind("<Motion>",self.motion)
        self.drawingArea.bind("<ButtonPress-1>",self.b1down)
        self.drawingArea.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>",self.b1up)
    def b1down(self,event):
        self.b1="down"
    def b1up(self,event):
        self.b1="up"
        self.xold=None
        self.yold=None
        self.liste.append((self.xold,self.yold))
    def motion(self,event):
        if self.b1=="down":
            if self.xold is not None and self.yold is not None:
                event.widget.create_line(self.xold,self.yold,event.x,event.y,fill="red",width=3,smooth=TRUE)
                self.top.draw_line(self.xold,self.yold,event.x,event.y)
            self.xold=event.x
            self.yold=event.y
            self.liste.append((self.xold,self.yold))

class TopLevelWindow(Frame):
    def __init__(self):   
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.top=Toplevel()
        self.top.wm_title("Second Window")
        self.canvas=Canvas(self.top,width=400,height=400)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=N+E+S+W)

        self.sbarv=Scrollbar(self,orient=VERTICAL)
        self.sbarh=Scrollbar(self,orient=HORIZONTAL)
        self.sbarv.config(command=self.canvas.yview)
        self.sbarh.config(command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.canvas.config(yscrollcommand=self.canvas.yview)
        self.canvas.config(xscrollcommand=self.canvas.xview)
        self.sbarv.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=N+S)
        self.sbarh.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W+E)
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=(0,0,400,400))


    def draw_line(self, xold, yold, x, y):
        self.canvas.create_line(xold,yold,x,y,fill="blue",width=3,smooth=TRUE)


if __name__=="__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.wm_title("Main Window")
    v = Test(root)
    v.test()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Looks like the `self.canvas.config(yscrollcommand=self.canvas.yview)` line and the one following it are the problem. Don't know how you'd fix it though.

Comment: @Kevin Thank you. It fixes the errors but not the second problem: scrollbars still not displayed. Everything else is ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to share the solution I found in case someone in the future encounters this problem:

I only had  encrust the  two scrollbars into the same parent widget as the canvas itself. I mean:

```
self.sbarv=Scrollbar(self.top,orient=VERTICAL)
self.sbarh=Scrollbar(self.top,orient=HORIZONTAL)
```

Answer (score 2):

These lines are incorrect:

```
self.canvas.config(yscrollcommand=self.canvas.yview)
self.canvas.config(xscrollcommand=self.canvas.xview)
```

You're telling the canvas to scroll the canvas when the canvas scrolls. The `yscrollcommand` and `xscrollcommand` options typically need to call the `set` method of a scrollbar:

```
self.canvas.config(yscrollcommand=self.sbarv.set)
self.canvas.config(xscrollcommand=self.sbarh.set)
```

Comment: Thank you. The errors disappeared totally. However I still do not see the scrollbars on the top level window